# Django model design: editable help text for individual model fields. Is there a foreign field that references a specific field of a model?

Tags: django, django-models, model

I have several models with several fields in my app. I want to set up a way for the user to be able to modify a help text system for each field in the model. Can you give me some guidance on how to design the models, and what field types to use? I don't feel right about storing the model and field name in CharFields, but if that is the only way, I may be stuck with it.

Is there a more elegant solution using Django?

For a quick and silly example, with an app named jobs, one named fun, and make a new app named helptext:

```
jobs.models.py:

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    .
    .
    interests = models.TextField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Job(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    address = models.TextField()
    duties = models.TextField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name



fun.models.py:

class RollerCoaster(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    scare_factor = models.PositiveInteger()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class BigDipper(RollerCoaster):
    max_elevation = models.PositiveInteger()
    best_comment_ever_made = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return super.name
```

Now, let's say I want to have editable help text on `Person.interests`, and `Job.duties`, `RollerCoaster.scare_factor`, and `BigDipper.best_comment_ever_made`. I'd have something like:

```
helptext.models.py:

from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class HelpText(models.Model):
    the_model = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    the_field = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    helptext = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.helptext
```

So, what is the better way to do this, other than making `HelpText.the_model` and `HelpText.the_field` CharFields that have to be compared when I am rendering the template to see if helptext is associated with each field on the screen?

Thanks in advance!

***Edit:***

I know about the help_text parameter of the fields, but I want this to be easily edited through the GUI, and it may contain a LOT of help with styling, etc. It would be HTML with probably upwards of 50-60 lines of text for probably 100 different model fields. I don't want to store it in the field definition for those reasons.

I changed the HelpText model to have a reference to ContentType and the field a CharField. Does this seem like a good solution? I am not sure this is the most elegant way. Please advise.

***Edit 2013-04-19 16:53 PST:***

Currently, I tried this and it works, but not sure this is great:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

# Field choices for the drop down.
FIELDS = ()

# For each ContentType verify the model_class() is not None and if not, add a tuple
# to FIELDS with the model name and field name displayed, but storing only the field
# name.
for ct in ContentType.objects.all():
    m = ct.model_class()
    if m is not None:
        for f in ct.model_class()._meta.get_all_field_names():
            FIELDS += ((f, str(ct.model) + '.' + str(f)),)


# HelpText model, associated with multiple models and fields.
class HelpText(models.Model):
    the_model = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    the_field = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=FIELDS)
    helptext = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.helptext
```

Doesn't feel like the best, but please advise if this is a solution that will bite me in the behind later on and make me filled with regrets... :*(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution works, and I have it implemented, but you have to be aware that sometimes the ContentTypes get out of sync with your models. You can manually update the content types with this:

```
python manage.py shell
>>> from django.contrib.contenttypes.management import update_all_contenttypes
>>> update_all_contenttypes(interactive=True)
```

This allows you to add the new ones and remove the old ones, if they exist.

The nice thing about the Field not being a foreign key is that I can put anything in it for help text. So, say I have a field "First Name." I can put a helptext connected to the Person model and the "first_name" field. I can also make something up, like "Something really confusing." The helptext is now associated with the Person model and the "Something really confusing" field. So, I can put it at the top of the form, instead of associating to a field with hard foreign keying. It can be anything arbitrary and will follow with that "field" anywhere. The hangup would be that you may change the name of the helptext field association inadvertently sending your original helptext into never land.

To make this easy, I created a TemplateTag, which I pass the name of the model and the name of the "field" I want to associate. Then anytime the template is rendered, that helptext is there, editable for anybody to get assistance with their user interface forms.

Not sure this is the best solution, but I couldn't really see any other way to do it, and got no responses.

Cheerio!